# Bootstrap icons hide frequently

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

We are using Bootmetro (Bootstrap theme) in our website. I found that frequently the icomoon icons are not displayed. After 6-7 refreshes it appears again. I though this was fault of browser. So i opened site in another browser (moment while icons gets disappears). But it doesnt appeared in other browser.

Any idea why these icons disappear frequently? (at one time all icons on all page together goes down)

Answer (score 2):

Which browser are you using?

This looks potentially relevant: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/21653/issue-with-icon-fonts-in-chrome-23/p1

Or this: [Is there a known glitch with using IcoMoon fonts and viewing on Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203929/is-there-a-known-glitch-with-using-icomoon-fonts-and-viewing-on-chrome)